# Error al enviar email desde python

Tags: python, python-3.x, email

Estoy haciendo pruebas para enviar mails con python. A la hora de enviar el mail, me devuelve el siguiente mensaje. Ya abrí el puerto desde el firewall.

El error es:
[WinError 10061] No se puede establecer una conexión ya que el equipo de destino denegó expresamente dicha conexión

El código es el siguiente:

```
    def enviar_mail (self, mail, contrarec):
    
    destinatario = mail.get()
    
    host = 'localhost'
    port = 587
    usuario = '******'
    contrasenha = '*****'

    email_from = "******@gmail.com"
    message = f"""\
    Subject: Enviar correo con python
    To: {email_from}
    From: {destinatario}
    ¡Hola! Este es un mensaje enviado desde Python"""

    try:
        with smtplib.SMTP(host, port) as server:
            server.login(usuario, contrasenha)
            server.sendmail(email_from, email_to, message)
    except Exception as e:
        print('Error enviando el correo')
        print(e)
    else:
        message.showinfo(message='Correo enviado')
```

Comment: ¿Seguro que te puedes conectar al puerto 25 en la máquina de destino? ¿Probaste con telnet?

Comment: ¿Y eso cómo puedo saberlo? Ya que se supone que el destinatario es una persona X

Comment: Con problemas de correo se usa "telnet host port" para chequear que el servidor esté escuchando en la puerta y que acepte conexiones. Luego prueba a ingresar un correo a mano siguiendo el protocolo SMTP. Con eso puedes detectar si te bloquean por seguridad.

Comment: En qué me ayudaría?

Comment: Así sabrias si el problema es ambiental o de tu código.

Comment: El problema era de mi código, me faltaba esta línea 'server = smtplib.SMTP(host, port)'. Ahora me tira este error 'SMTP AUTH extension not supported by server.'

Comment: Prueba a enviar el mail sin hacer el login.